# Up to date custom ROM vs outdated official ROM: which is more secure?

Tags: android

### Question 1:

Which is more secure between an **up to date custom ROM** and an **outdated official ROM** ?

### Question 2:

If an up to date custom ROM is more secure, why is Google making it harder to pass SafetyNet on them than on outdated official ROMs ?

### Details:

**Up to date custom ROM:**

- Android security patch: latest
- Google Play system update: latest
- Bootloader: unlocked
- Rooted: no

**Outdated official ROM:**

- Android security patch: 2+ years old
- Google Play system update: latest
- Bootloader: locked
- Rooted: no

**Threat model:** average user with several banking apps

Comment: @defalt As I specified in my question, I am an average user with several banking apps.  Nothing out of the ordinary. I don't know what kind of attackers targets people like me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This question is not straightforward to answer: "What's more secure; something up-to-date but completely unknown, or a known and tested but out of date?" That's like asking "how long is a piece of string?" The answer is: "it depends on the string"

Comment: @schroeder Then lets say Lineage OS up to date, vs Oxygen OS 2 years old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. An updated custom ROM is more secure, as long as it's from a trustworthy source (e.g., LineageOS).
2. Because SafetyNet, etc. aren't about keeping you secure. They're about keeping app developers' stuff secure *from you*.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Then, I should probably ask another question, because I don't understand the purpose of SafetyNet. The app developers should not rely on a client integrity check because they should never trust the client in the first place. And indeed, SafetyNet is easily bypassed.