# Why does SafetyNet target non-rooted custom ROMs?

Tags: android

I understand that a rooted phone exposes its user to security issues, because a malware could do more damage in a rooted environment than in a non-rooted one.

But why target up-to-date, non-rooted custom ROMs like Lineage ?

In [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/273781/302618), it is said

> SafetyNet, etc. aren't about keeping you secure. They're about keeping app developers' stuff secure *from you*.

I dont understand why app developers should rely on a client integrity check. I thought the backend should never trust the client in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought the backend should never trust the client in the first place.

It should avoid it whenever possible. Sometimes it is not possible though.

For example if you want to write an app which is able to download copyright protected content onto a users device, then you must be able to trust the device to protect the data *in the interest of the copyright owner, not the device owner*. With a ROM which is not in control of a trusted vendor you don't get this kind of assurance, no matter if rooted or not.

Also, if you want to assure security properties like the ability to protect private keys from extraction, then you must be able to ensure that the running system is the one which is trusted for doing this. With a custom ROM one cannot ensure this, no matter if rooted or not.

Comment: This is important. SafetyNet is not there to protect *you*. It's there to protect others, like Netflix, your bank and Google.

Comment: @vidarlo: I would give it a slightly different spin: it is not there to protect others, but the business model of others. It's like doing a background check before giving a loan to reduce the risk of the one giving the loan. For some business models one cannot simply trust the other one to tell the truth but one needs to have a trusted third party to do the necessary checks.

Comment: But Netflix and the banks happily send me data when I use a web browser on the same exact custom ROM though. Why don't they need an integrity check in this case ?

Comment: If I log into my bank via an app, a token is stored on the phone, and to access that token it requires an fingerprint. On a rooted phone I could access that token directly. In the browser they ask for a password every time. So it's a different risk to the bank.

Comment: @Evolve: in addition to what vidarlo said: on a verified device Netflix might provide you with better video resolution, ability to store videos for offline use etc, but only within the app and not the browser (since verification can only be done from the app).

Comment: @vidarlo on an ARM Android device, there are things not even *root* can do. Before your "unlocked" bootloader runs, a very *very* vendor-locked (probably immutable) pre-bootloader runs and configures things like ARM TrustZone. Once triggered, not even root can use them in ways the pre-boot firmware prohibits. In the case of things like stored credential tokens, I think it works like Blu-Ray data across a PCIe bus... the computer itself provides a transport layer for the key exchange, but the key itself used to encrypt the token locally comes from Netflix, your bank, etc.

Comment: @vidarlo (continued) In many cases, SafetyNet is more paranoid than it needs to be. A custom ROM can *trivially* lie to an app that uses Android's coarse-location or fine-location API... but spoofing your location to an app that uses Google Play Location Service is another matter **entirely**. And Google Play has the keys (issued to the vendor, and baked into its most secret innermost TrustZone locker) allowing it to make TrustZone calls that "mere" root can't. It also has the ability to independently validate for itself that apps calling Play APIs have not been tampered with.

Comment: @vidarlo (continued, #2) In a very real sense, even an AOSP rom on a Pixel with unlocked bootloader is basically jailed inside a hardware-level hypervisor enforced by TrustZone. If you're *lucky*, the phone gives you a way to non-permanently disable TrustZone (and everything contained within it) at boot (getting out of your way, while making its contents untouchable by you until the next shutdown & reboot). If you're NOT lucky, the phone might pull a "Sony" and literally BLOW AWAY those keys forever upon unlocking the bootloader (so you can't *ever* go back if you change your mind).

Comment: @Bitbang3r Interesting, thanks for educating me :)